# Is there a way to cycle through Bootstrap tabs automatically (similar to carousel)?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tabs, cycle

I would like the Bootstrap tabs to cycle through each tab, kind of like a carousel, changing every 10 seconds or so. I figure it's going to require some custom javascript (but I'm a bit of a novice)!

(I'd also like the cycle to stop if a tab has been manually clicked, but that's more of a 'stretch goal'!)

Here's what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/59Lyhqmn/31/

I've tried implementing solutions from similar questions, such as:

```
$(function(){
var tabs = $('#myTab a');
    var counter = 0;
    window.setInterval(activateTab, 1000);
    function activateTab(){

       tabs.removeClass('active');
       var currentLink = tabs[counter];

       $('.tab-pane').removeClass('.active').hide();
       currentLink.addClass('active');
       $(currentLink.attr('href')).addClass('active').show();
       if(counter  < tabs.length)
         counter= counter + 1;
       else 
         counter = 0;
    }
});
```

but I've had no luck so far!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your fiddle I came up with the solution using simple iteration
**JSFiddle Link** [Working](http://jsfiddle.net/ShubhamKaudewar/u3dmkvcy/1/)

```
    $(function(){
    var count = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
    if(count == 1){
      $("ul>li:nth-child(4)>a").removeClass("active");
      $("ul>li:nth-child(1)>a").addClass("active");
      $("#first-tab").addClass("active show in");
      $("#fourth-tab").removeClass("active show in");
    }
    else if(count == 2){
      $("ul>li:nth-child(2)>a").addClass("active");
      $("ul>li:nth-child(1)>a").removeClass("active");
      $("#second-tab").addClass("active show in");
      $("#first-tab").removeClass("active show in");
    }
    else if(count == 3){
      $("ul>li:nth-child(3)>a").addClass("active");
      $("ul>li:nth-child(2)>a").removeClass("active");
      $("#third-tab").addClass("active show in");
      $("#second-tab").removeClass("active show in");
    }
    else if(count == 4){
      $("ul>li:nth-child(4)>a").addClass("active");
      $("ul>li:nth-child(3)>a").removeClass("active");
      $("#fourth-tab").addClass("active show in");
      $("#third-tab").removeClass("active show in");
    }
    if (count == 4){count=1;}else{count+=1}
  }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked beautifully! If I were to add a second set of tabs, how would I go about differentiating them from the first set? At the moment, when the first set of tabs is updated, it also updates the second set - I'd like them to be independent, if possible? Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/73jwhky5/

Comment: There are 2 ways Either access children by parent div id or put individual unique IDs to everyone and write another js inside onload ready function

Answer (score 1):

The following solution seems to be more approachable and it is based on Bootstrap Framework 3.4 and above, the above code didn't changed the panel and also it can cause conflicts between your other navigation active status as well.

Peace out
Happy Coding.

```
       $(function(){
            var count = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                if(count === 1){
                    $('#myTab a[href="#home"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
                }
                else if(count === 2){
                    $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
                }
                else if(count === 3){
                    $('#myTab a[href="#contact"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
                }
                else if(count === 4){
                    $('#myTab a[href="#packaging"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
                }
                if (count === 4){count=1;}else{count+=1}
            }, 2000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 4 or higher version. below script work

```
function tabChange() {
    var tabs = $('.nav-tabs > li');
    var active = $('.nav-tabs > li').find('a.active');
    var next = active.parent('li').next('li').find('a');
    if (next.length === 0) {
      next = $('.nav-tabs > li').first().find('a').click();
   }
    next.tab('show');
}
var tabCycle = setInterval(tabChange, 5000);
```